# How to move content in ul to the center HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to center this menu with links. "text-align: center;" in ul doesn't work and I've tried to find a solution for at least 1 hour now. I'm quite new to web developing, any help is appriciated.

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
background-color: #3A3A3A;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

li {
display: inline;
float: left;
font-size: 22px
}

li a {
display: block;
padding: 20px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
color: #00DBFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="login.html"><b>LOGIN</b></a></li>
<li><a href="register.html"><b>REGISTER</b></a></li>
<li><a href="dam.html"><b>DAM</b></a></li>
<li><a href="herr.html"><b>MÄN</b></a></li>
<li><a href="exempel.html"><b>EXEMPEL</b></a></li>
<li><a href="test.html"><b>TEST</b></a></li>
<li><a href="logout.html"><b>LOGOUT</b></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want do? it's not clear what you want. You want the Item be one under the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li {
    display: inline;
    /*float: left;*/  /* <----- */
    font-size: 22px
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;  /* <----- */
    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0b0vudf/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #3A3A3A;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  font-size: 22px
}
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  color: #00DBFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="login.html"><b>LOGIN</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="register.html"><b>REGISTER</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="dam.html"><b>DAM</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="herr.html"><b>MÄN</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="exempel.html"><b>EXEMPEL</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="test.html"><b>TEST</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="logout.html"><b>LOGOUT</b></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Try this if you want to: `li {text-align: center;}`